# I didn't understand the statement in the for loop! can any one please elaborate this?

Tags: java

```
int[] a = new int[101];
int n = in.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
  a[in.nextInt()]++; 
}
```

Comment: If `in.nextInt()` returns numbers between 0 and 100, it is counting the frequency of each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array that is initialized; the next line get's you the amount of numbers that will follow after that.
Assuming that `in` is an initialized `Scanner`, `nextInt()` will read the next `int` from the console. Usually on websites like codingames.com or apparently hackerrank use this construct to put in data for your code to test it.

In the loop the code will read an index to be used in the pre-initialized array  to increase the value by one at that given index.

That is basically it. To make it clearer, you could write:

```
int[] a = new int[101];
int numberOfIntsToFollow = in.nextInt();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIntsToFollow; i++){ 
  int x = in.nextInt();
  a[x]++; 
}
```